# Ireland Tax : Indian Passport holder

Tags: taxes, ireland

I am Indian passport holder and going to Dublin, Ireland for 1 year.

If I my salary is 3400 Euro monthly then how much in hand salary I will get after tax deduction.

Comment: You can probably also ask this on our [Personal Finance site,](http://money.stackexchange.com)  where lots of people knowledgeable about taxes from many countries hang out

Answer (score 3):

You can figure it out easily here: http://www.pwc.ie/campaigns/budget/irish-budget-2015-2016/2016-calculator.html